# Ball bounce equation using pressure

Tags: experimental-physics

Is there an equation that can calculate how high a rubber ball rebounds after being dropped? I will be using the pressure of the ball as a variable. I will drop the ball from a height of 1.5m with varying pressure, and I would like to have a model to test.

Comment: Pressure of what?

Comment: The pressure of the ball

Comment: not sure why this question was closed. makes perfectly good sense to me. I find sometimes this site has a bias toward assuming that short questions, and questions with imperfect english, are poorly described questions that "need details or clarity". Of course, the answer is just "no." This situation is far too complicated for there to be a simple equation giving the answer. You'd have to make a model yourself.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I reworded the text to make it more understandable (and frankly to appeal to picky stack exchange users). If you don't like what I've done, you can revert it to your original text or edit it again yourself.

Comment: You can develop your own equation.  Film the bouncing ball with different pressures, plot the points, and curve fit an equation through those points.